# Send Email PhantomJS With Mailgun

Tags: phantomjs

I have some code to send email with phantomjs 
But, i always get fail. 
What's wrong with my code?

```
    function ObjToQs(obj) {
      str = '';
      for(key in obj) {
        str += key + '=' + obj[key] + '&';
      }
      str = str.slice(0, str.length - 1);
    return str;
    }

    var page = require("webpage").create();
    var URL = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/xxxxxxx.mailgun.org";
    var from = "xxx@xxx.com";
    var to = "jxxx@xxxx.com";
    var data = {
    "from" : from,
    "to" : to,
    "subject" : "Hello!",
    "text": "Test from mailgun / phantomjs"
    };

    page.customHeaders = {
      "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("api:xxxx")
    }

    page.open(URL, "POST", data, function(status){
      if (status === "success") {
        console.log("Send Email Success!");
        var result = page.evaluate(function () {
          return document.body.innerText;
        });

        console.log("Log Result: " + result);
        phantom.exit();
      } else {
        console.log('FAIL to load the log');
        console.log(status);
      }
    })
```

I want to send some error log, when i run phantomjs 
I've tried several times
But it still did not work
Maybe someone can help me